# How can I turn my javascript callback flow into a Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
function getMentionedUsers(str, next){
    var array = getUsernamesFromString(str); //['john','alex','jess'];
    if(array.length > 0){
        var users = [];
        var pending = array.length;
        array.forEach(function(username){
            getUserByUsername(username).then(function(model){
                users.push(model.key);
                --pending || next(users); //this is a callback model
            }); 
        });
    }
};

function getUserByUsername(username){
    return admin.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('username').equalTo(username).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val(); //this is the firebase example of a promise
    });
};
```

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
    getMentionedUsers(model.body, function(users){
        console.log("Mentions", users);
    });
```

However, I'd like to turn `getMentionedUsers` into a promise.  How can I do that? I'm new to Promises

Comment: arrayofpromises

Comment: Message to the down voter: please substantiate why you would down vote this great question ?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to call `next` at all when the `array` is empty?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Promise.all` and `Array#map`:

```
function getMentionedUsers(str) {
  return Promise.all(getUsernamesFromString(str).map((username) => {
    return getUserByUsername(username).then((model) => model.key);
  }));
}
```

A more readable version broken into two functions:

```
function getUserKeyByUsername(username) {
  return getUserByUsername(username).then((user) => user.key);
}

function getMentionedUsers(str) {
  const promises = getUsernamesFromString(str).map(getUserKeyByUsername);
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Great. Upvoted. :)
@WillemD'Haeseleer if you've ever worked with other programmers, you'll know why it's unreadable. Just because you can fit everything on one line doesn't mean you should!

Comment: @mrBorna if you ever worked with functional programming, you'll know why chaining methods isn't all that bad

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all`.

```
const getMentionedUsers = str =>
        Promise.all(
            getUsernamesFromString(str).map(
                username => getUserByUsername(username)
                    .then(model => model.key)
            )
        );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

You can have the best of both. If you pass a `next` function, it will get called with the results. If not, your method will return a promise.

```
function getMentionedUsers(str, next){
    var array = getUsernamesFromString(str); //['john','alex','jess'];
    var promise = Promise.resolve([]); // default 
    var hasNext = typeof next === 'function';
    if(array.length > 0){
        promise = Promise.all(array.map(function(username){
            return getUserByUsername(username); 
        }));
    }
    promise = promise.then(models => {
        var users = models.map(model => model.key);
        if (hasNext) next(null, users);
        return users;
    });
    if (hasNext) promise.catch(next);
    else return promise;
};
```

**UPDATE:** Though not part of your original question, this is still a good point and worth pointing out. Your existing code is using a non-standard callback technique. The standard callback technique expects an error as the first parameter and results as a second parameter:

```
next(new Error(...)); //-> when something fails
next(null, results); //-> when something succeeds
```

As such, I have updated my code to show the "standard" callback behavior alongside promises. Using the hybrid approach above allows for existing code to stay in place while allowing new code to use the new Promise technique. This would be considered a "non-breaking change".

Comment: I would not recommend this. When using callbacks with this code any errors that might occur when getting the user will be completely ignored. 
You are essentially getting the worst of both worlds really. I would recommend to only use promises. Or at the very least use standard callbacks if you must use callbacks.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer - I added the `catch` code so errors are not lost. Thanks for pointing that out. His original code swallowed errors too... just sayin'.  As far as choosing one over the other, there are libraries which do this and it's a useful feature. Also, by supporting both he doesn't have to rewrite all the code which calls this function. If this is part of open source code, he wouldn't have to use a major release just to get the new "promise" feature out.

Comment: You are still using non standard callbacks with makes it impossible to deal with error propagation. The fact that the original code was already broken is not a good reason to not fix it.

Comment: That's a separate issue though, he asked how to convert his function to promise based. His original code was broken in that sense, not my answer. I was just showing him how he could do both - which is really useful and is used by libs like Mongoose.

Comment: I'm gonna have to strongly disagree, pointing out the issues in OP's code is the whole point why OP posted in the first place. He has working code already and specifically asked how this could be done better due to his inexperience in the domain.

Comment: The OP posted for this: `"I'd like to turn getMentionedUsers into a promise. How can I do that?"` - but you seem pretty intent on this whole misuse of callbacks thing, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

using native ES6 promises, written in a functional style:

```js
// Returns array of usernames
function getUsernamesFromString(str = '') {
  return str.split(',').map(s => s.trim())
}

// returns promise of user
function getUserByUserName(username) {
  // Lets say this is a slow async function and returns a promise
  return Promise.resolve({
    id: (Math.random() * 10 ** 10).toFixed(0),
    username
  });
}

function getMentionedUsers(str) {
  return Promise.all(
    getUsernamesFromString(str).map(getUserByUserName)
  );
}

getMentionedUsers('kai, ava, mia, nova').then(console.log.bind(console))
```

However, there are also libraries like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) that can promisify objects and functions automatically as long as the follow the NODE convention of `(err, result)` as the callback arguments.

You can also just return a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* all your code */ })` and just call `resolve(dataToResolveWith)` if it succeeds and `reject(new Error())` if it fails, but you rarely have to do that and in fact, it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: How do I get an array of user keys at the end?

Comment: This answer is a little over elaborative, also the code snippet doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @TIMEX updated it to wait for the promise at the end.
It will return a list of users which you can map to the ID's if you want